# Rails: find related records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, tags

I'm using act-as-taggable gem and want to sort similar article to a given article based on maximum similar tags, for example i have an article that i must show their related articles and is tagged with

`([“awesome”, “cool”, "foo", "bar", "rails"])`

and anothers tagged with

A1= `([“awesome”, “cool”, "foo", "bar", "rails"])`

A2= `([“awesome”, “cool”, "foo", "bar", "python"])`

A3= `([“awesome”, “cool”, "foo", "python", "django"])`

in the sorting of related article A1 must be the first followed by A2 & finally A3 Howa can I achieve this

actually what i'm doing is `@related_articles = Article.tagged_with(@article.tag_list, any: true)` but this show all tags with only one similar tags so even if there is some articles with 5 or 4 similar tags they will not be first, the other solution is to use `:match_all => true` but if there is no article with all this tag the related article will be nil, So I'm wondering on how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this gem, but you could do it this way. Assuming the main article you want to get similar articles from is named `@article` and its tags are accessible via `@article.tag_list`, you could do:

1 - Get all the articles that match any of the tags from `@article`:

```
@related_articles = Article.tagged_with(@article.tag_list, any: true)
```

2 - Sort them afterwards by doing:

```
@related_articles.sort_by { |ra| (ra.tag_list & @article.tag_list).size }.reverse
```

The key here is the `&` operator. Play with it on the console :)

Comment: It seem that is a working solution I haven't tested it a lot yet but tank you